# How to make an gmail API call when I am having ACCESS TOKEN in JSP?

Tags: jsp, oauth-2.0, gmail, gmail-api

How to do the API call if I am having access token.There is lack of examples to research on it.I want to read my mailbox and sync those mails to my local machine.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/quickstart-java#step_4_run_the_sample

Comment: I don't understand your question, are you asking how to authenticate your session?

Comment: Nope.I am saying that if I am having token then how to do the API call using that token.